# H2 database corruption on a regular basis

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-jdbc

i'm the developper of [an open-source application](https://github.com/gotson/komga) designed for self-hosting. As such, it is used by many people on various systems, OSes, and hardware. It's built using Kotlin and Spring Boot, and uses H2 as the database. The problem i have is that many users are facing database corruption from times to times (it happened to me also a few times).

The corruptions are always of the form:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 20221 not found [1.4.200/9]" [50000-200]
```

I can't pinpoint any particular reason for those corruptions. The application doesn't use any dangerous H2 options. I couldn't find anything on the web or Stackoverflow that relates to my (imho) mundane use of H2.

---

I'm using:

- Spring Boot `2.2.6.RELEASE`
- jOOQ `3.13.1` (but i had the same issues before with Hibernate)
- H2 `1.4.200`

The connection string is pretty straightforward:

```
jdbc:h2:~/.komga/database.h2
```

The application is doing heavy writes once in a while (during file system scanning), but afterwards it's doing mostly reads.

---

**Would you have suggestions on how to better configure H2 to avoid those issues ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If your application uses `Thread.interrupt()` for threads doing calls into embedded database, this is the reason of corruption, don't do this or use the `async:` filesystem (`jdbc:h2:async:…`).
2. If classloader with H2 can be forcibly unloaded (on some application servers, for example) or application is going to be terminated in some abnormal way, you need to close all connections before it or execute the `SHUTDOWN` command and wait for its completion.
3. If you try to open the database file with some older version of H2, it can corrupt the file created by a more recent version.
4. You may run into some bug in H2, so if you can build a standalone test case (Java / JDBC / SQL only, no third-party libraries), you need to fill a new issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues). You can also try to build H2 from its current sources, there were some changes in the storage backend, but current H2 is very different from 1.4.200 in other aspects and third-partly libraries that you use may be not yet ready to work with it.
5. You can use the legacy PageStore backend instead of default one by appending `;MV_STORE=FALSE` to the JDBC URL when you create your database. This backend uses table-level locks (you need to lock tables in the same order in all your transactions) and doesn't execute commands from different sessions in parallel, but it is more reliable.
6. You can use a separate H2 Server process; such configuration is usually more reliable than embedded databases, but it works slower.
7. In any case, with any DBMS, you should create backup copies on regular basis. H2 has [`BACKUP`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#backup) command for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that's insightful. For 1. I don't use `Thread.interrupt()`, but maybe Spring does ? I have no way of knowing that. Can i use the `async` filesystem with an existing database, or do i have to create the db from scratch? For 2. I have no control on the user's systems, they could have a hard reboot for instance, i cannot do anything about that. If there's nothing to do for those, i would better switch to another DB engine, no? 3. and 4. do not apply to my case. 5. would need me to recreate the DB, which i can't. For 7. we have backups but they can also get corrupt.

Comment: `async:` can be used with existing databases, but it can't be enabled or disabled by application on the fly. First connection determines a file system abstraction layer to use. You need to close the database (close all connections or possibly use the `SHUTDOWN` command, especially if `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` was used) to re-open it with another file system.

Comment: Is it fair to say that if I have no control on hard reboots, H2 is not the right choice?

Comment: Default MVStore backend still doesn't like them sometimes, PageStore should work better, but you can consider other DBMS as well if you don't need something special. Derby, HSQLDB, and H2 are very different in many aspects.

Comment: with H2 2.1.210, MV_STORE=FALSE does not work.

Comment: It is not expected to work in newest versions of H2, PageStore backend was removed and stability of MVStore was significantly improved. But you shouldn't use outdated 2.1.210, various issues were fixed in 2.1.212.